# db:migrate with postgres. How to fix users already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

Have another question on here and am trying not to ask to many but keep hitting walls left and right. Running db:migrate with postgres and getting the below error. How to fix users already exists?

```
$ rake db:migrate
==  CreateUsers: migrating ====================================================
-- create_table(:users)
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "users_id_seq1" for serial column "users.id"
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PGError: ERROR:  relation "users" already exists
: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" serial primary key, "first_name" character varying(25),     "last_name" character varying(50), "email" character varying(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,    "password" character varying(40), "created_at" timestamp, "updated_at" timestamp) 

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

rb file below

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string "first_name", :limit => 25
      t.string "last_name", :limit => 50
      t.string "email", :default => "", :null => false
      t.string "password", :limit => 40
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Comment: Is this on a production app or on your local development machine?  If it's development, do a `rake db:reset` and then try the migration again

Answer (score 2):

You can place a command before the `create_table :users do |t|` to drop the table do `drop_table :users`. ONLY DO THIS IF YOU HAVE NO DATA TO LOSE!

If you want to added columns put `add_column` for each line eg. `add_column :users, :name, :string`

Comment: I ended up fixing this another way...It was late and now I don't remember how I fixed it. Resolved. Thx for the input Mab879 :)